# ¿Como llamar al id de mi base de datos SQL y mostrarlo en una consulta con PHP?

Tags: php, html, sql

tengo un formulario, en el ingresan datos personales los usuarios. Hice un if, para que el CURP no se repitiera, si el curp se repite manda una alerta diciéndoles que está repetido y los regresa al formulario, en eso no tengo problema me parece, pero en el else de esa condición, es decir cuando se ingresa un curp que no está repetido en la base, ejecuta la inserción de los datos que llenó el usuario en el formulario a la base de datos y después de eso, hago una declaración de variables llamando los datos que llenó el usuario con el método $_REQUEST y al final los imprimo, pero lo que quiero es que también imprima el id del usuario que se está registrando, para ello requiero de una consulta en mi base de datos y lo que quiero es que se seleccione el id del usuario donde mi campo CURP sea igual al CURP que ingresó en usuario, para indicarle que ese es su id y que debe de guardarlo, pero no me sale, este es mi código.

```
<?php
 $conexion=mysql_connect("localhost","id6681618_pagina26","aldair1234")
 or die ("Problemas en la conexion");
 mysql_select_db("id6681618_pagina26",$conexion)
 or die("Problemas en la conexion de la base de datos");
 $inscripciones=mysql_query("SELECT FOLIO, CURP
 FROM inscripciones where
 CURP='$_REQUEST[CURP]'",$conexion) or
 die("Problemas en el select:".mysql_error());

 if($reg=mysql_fetch_array($inscripciones))
 {
   $mensaje = "Este CURP ya fue ingresado, por favor intenta nuevamente.";
 echo "<script>";
 echo "alert('$mensaje');";
 echo "history.back();";
 echo "</script>";
 //redirect('formulario.html', 'refresh');
 //header( "refresh:5;url=formulario.html" );



}
```

Este es el else:

```
else
 {

  mysql_query("insert into inscripciones(NOMBRE, APELLIDOPA, APELLIDOMA, CURP) values ('$_REQUEST[NOMBRE]','$_REQUEST[APELLIDOPA]','$_REQUEST[APELLIDOMA]','$_REQUEST[CURP]')", $conexion) or die("Problemas en el select".mysql_error());
mysql_close($conexion);
 print '<script language="JavaScript">'; 


print 'alert("Proceso terminado");';

    print '</script>'; 

    }
```

Después hago mis variables y acaba el PHP:

```
$nom=$_REQUEST['NOMBRE'];
$apellipa=$_REQUEST['APELLIDOPA'];
$apellima=$_REQUEST['APELLIDOMA'];
$curp=$_REQUEST['CURP'];
?>
```

Y ahora siguen las impresiones, o sea la consulta, esto es para que el usuario revise si están correctos o no sus datos, pero no me muestra el id de primera, aparece en blanco, al recargar la página me lo muestra, pero el código del CURP me regresa inmediatamente al formulario.

```
<h1>Verifica que los datos que ingresaste sean correctos, si así lo es, presiona para generar tu ficha.</h1>


 <form action="eliminar.php">


 <div  class="col-4">
    <label>
      FOLIO
    <input name="FOLIO" type="text"  disabled="false" value="<?php echo $reg['FOLIO']; ?>" />    
    </label>
  </div>

   <div  class="col-4">
    <label>
      NOMBRE
      <input name="NOMBRE" type="text"  disabled="false" value="<?php echo $nom ?>" />    
      </label>
  </div>


<div class="col-4">
    <label>
      APELLIDO PATERNO
      <input name="APELLIDOPA" type="text" disabled="false" value="<?php echo $apellipa ?>" />
    </label>
  </div>


  <div class="col-4">
    <label>
      APELLIDO MATERNO
      <input name="APELLIDOMA" type="text" disabled="false" value="<?php echo $apellima?>" />
    </label>
  </div>


  <div class="col-3">
    <label>
      CURP
      <input name="CURP" type="text" disabled="false" value="<?php echo $curp ?>" />
    </label>
  </div>
```

Les agradecería mucho si pueden ayudarme, llevo varios días pensando como hacerlo. :'v

Comment: ¿Necesitas obtener el identificador del registro que has creado con el INSERT? Para ello tienes que usar una llamada del estilo mysql_insert_id aunque ésta es una llamada obsoleta. Si estás usando mysqli tienes una equivalente aunque lo mejor sería que usaras un framework del estilo de Laravel

Answer (score 0):

antes que nada la función **mysql** ya es obsoleta, en la versiones nuevas de PHP se usa **mysqli**  así que tendrías que actualizar tu código.

Acá te dejo tu código con algunas mejoras

**Tu formulario Principal :** (Formulario.php)

```
<form action="procesar.php" method="POST">
  <div  class="col-6"><label>NOMBRE</label>
    <input name="NOMBRE" type="text"  />    
  </div>
  <div class="col-6"><label>APELLIDO PATERNO</label>
    <input name="APELLIDOPA" type="text"/>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6"><label>APELLIDO MATERNO</label>
   <input name="APELLIDOMA" type="text"/>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6"><label>CURP</label>
    <input name="CURP" type="text"  />
  </div>
  <button type="submit" name="btnRegistrar">REGISTRAR</button>
</form>
```

**Luego en PHP** : (procesar.php)

```
<?php
$conexion=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","stackover");

if (isset($_POST['btnRegistrar'])) {
 $nom=$_REQUEST['NOMBRE'];
 $apellipa=$_REQUEST['APELLIDOPA'];
 $apellima=$_REQUEST['APELLIDOMA'];
 $curp=$_REQUEST['CURP'];
 $query = "SELECT FOLIO, CURP FROM inscripciones where CURP='$curp'";
 $inscripciones=mysqli_query($conexion,$query);

 if($reg=mysqli_fetch_array($inscripciones)){
   $mensaje = "Este CURP ya fue ingresado, por favor intenta nuevamente.";
   echo "<script>";
   echo "alert('$mensaje');";
   echo "history.back();";
   echo "</script>";
   //redirect('formulario.html', 'refresh');
   //header( "refresh:5;url=formulario.html" );
 } else {
   $instruccion = "INSERT INTO inscripciones(NOMBRE, APELLIDOPA, APELLIDOMA, CURP) values ('$nom','$apellipa','$apellima','$curp')";
   mysqli_query($conexion,$instruccion);
   print '<script language="JavaScript">'; 
   print 'alert("Proceso terminado");';
   print '</script>'; 
}
?>
<h1>Verifica que los datos que ingresaste sean correctos, si así lo es, presiona para generar tu ficha.</h1>
<form action="eliminar.php">
  <div  class="col-4"><label>FOLIO</label>
    <input name="FOLIO" type="text"  disabled="false" value="<?php echo $reg['FOLIO']; ?>" />    
  </div>
   <div  class="col-4"><label>NOMBRE</label>
      <input name="NOMBRE" type="text"  disabled="false" value="<?php echo $nom; ?>" />    
  </div>
  <div class="col-4"><label>APELLIDO PATERNO</label>
      <input name="APELLIDOPA" type="text" disabled="false" value="<?php echo $apellipa; ?>" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-4"><label>APELLIDO MATERNO</label>
      <input name="APELLIDOMA" type="text" disabled="false" value="<?php echo $apellima; ?>" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-4"><label>CURP</label>
      <input name="APELLIDOMA" type="text" disabled="false" value="<?php echo $curp; ?>" />
  </div>
</form>
<?php } else { echo ":("; } ?>
```

Espero ayudarte, Buen día =)

Comment: Lo probé y si funciona, pero al momento de dar click en el botón de registrar me manda directamente al else, no me imprime la consulta ni nada. :'v

Comment: Le pusiste el 'name' al boton registrar ?

Comment: Si, lo hice igual.

Comment: brindarme tu correo y así te paso el código :D

Comment: oscarreyescontacto@gmail.com